# Open URL with ASCII characters (emojis) on it as parameters with urllib

Tags: python-3.x, urllib, telegram-webhook

I'm making a telegram bot that sends messages to a Channel, everything works fine until I try to send a message with an ASCII character (like an emoji) inside the URL message parameter, whenever I try to run something like this:

```
botMessage = ''
urlRequest = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{telegram_token}/sendMessage?chat_id={chat_id}&text={botMessage}'
urlRequest = urlRequest.replace(" ", "%20")

urllib.request.urlopen(urlRequest)
```

I get this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\U0001f6a8' in position 95: ordinal not in range(128)
```

[Here is the full pic of all the errors I got before the one I wrote above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HTAj.png)

Comment: **That is not _remotely_ an ASCII character.** There are [only 95 printable ASCII characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_set) -- and [URLs can only use _some_ of them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). For others see https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#url-quoting .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-ASCII character is forbidden in URL. This is a limitation in `HTTP` protocol and it is not related to Telegram. Use `urllib.parse.quote` function to encode from UTF-8 to ASCII as follow:

```
import urllib.request
botMessage = urllib.parse.quote('')
urlRequest = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendMessage?chat_id={chat_id}&text={botMessage}'
urlRequest = urlRequest.replace(" ", "%20")

urllib.request.urlopen(urlRequest)
```

There are many python library for Telegram Bot. They are easy to use and they hide these details.